# netcdf4-python can't run in celery/django

Tags: python, django, netcdf

It works well as normal function(run in shell mode not django), But when I run the netcdf in celery task/django,It can't work,and show me this error:

```
File "...", line 53, in ...
    with Dataset(path, format='NETCDF4') as dataset:
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2291, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1855, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'/my/nc/path'
```

I checked the source code, May be the question is at the 2232 line in file `netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx`:

```
ierr = nc_open(path, NC_NOWRITE, &grpid)
```

But I don't know what's wrong with this code,and what is the different between use django and no django.

Comment: What versions of Python, Django and NetCDF4 are you using?

Comment: Is `path` indeed an absolute path here, as suggested by the (modified, I assume) error message?

Comment: Python 3.6.8  django  2.2.1 netcdf4 1.5.1.2.

Comment: Yes, path is an absolute path which is uploaded from client to server.

Comment: What -101 mean?I had not find the errorno who had miss.

Comment: The question is the same file can work well in shell mode,not in django. And if the mode set to 'w' or 'a' can work well too.

Comment: If the file is uploaded, are you trying to write it, or read it?

Comment: Yeah,I just want to read it,When I use ```with Dataset(path) as dataset:``` It show me this error.

Comment: I was thinking that the problem may have been with permissions when uploading (since the server user will have different permissions than your normal user), but I guess if the file is already there, this may not be an issue. Nevertheless, permissions may be something to check (the unclarity of the error may be a result of the fact that the error propagates from HDF5 to NetCDF4 to Python, which may lose the actual error).

Comment: Maybe not,My server just a develop environment, and it was the same user as shell.And I had test use django to read another file,But shows the same error.